# Getting multiple users from user field

Tags: user, user-information-list

I am trying to Get multiple users from user field in page load, and display loginName and navigate url in a hyperlinks in a repeater, but only the last user in the list are displayed?

in ascx page i have this code

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterLinks" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate >
   <asp:HyperLink ID="MyLinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LoginName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

In ascx.cs i have this

```
Guid fieldID8 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Field8").Id;
    string valueField8 = item[fieldID8].ToString();
    SPFieldUserValueCollection userField8 = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item.Fields[fieldID8].GetFieldValue(valueField8);

     foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in userField8)
     {
       string script = "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + value.User.ToString() + "')</script>";
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);

         SPUser spuserField = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(value.User.ToString());
          SPList userInformationList8 = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
         SPListItem userItem8 = userInformationList8.Items.GetItemById(spuserField.ID);


         SPServiceContext contextSp = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection);
        UserProfileManager profileManager8 = new UserProfileManager(contextSp);
          if (profileManager8.UserExists(spuserField.LoginName))
          {
              var profile8 = profileManager8.GetUserProfile(spuserField.LoginName);
               string personUrl8 = profile8.PersonalSite.Url;

                string userNames = userItem8["Title"].ToString();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("LoginName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    dt.Columns.Add("NavigateUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["LoginName"] = userNames;
                    row["NavigateUrl"] = personUrl8;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);

                    RepeaterLinks.DataSource = dt;
                    RepeaterLinks.DataBind();

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you are creating data table inside user loop of each user that's why it showing only last user. Correct code should be

```
    Guid fieldID8 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Field8").Id;
string valueField8 = item[fieldID8].ToString();
SPFieldUserValueCollection userField8 = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item.Fields[fieldID8].GetFieldValue(valueField8);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LoginName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("NavigateUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));
 foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in userField8)
 {
   string script = "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + value.User.ToString() + "')</script>";
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);

     SPUser spuserField = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(value.User.ToString());
      SPList userInformationList8 = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
     SPListItem userItem8 = userInformationList8.Items.GetItemById(spuserField.ID);


     SPServiceContext contextSp = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection);
    UserProfileManager profileManager8 = new UserProfileManager(contextSp);
      if (profileManager8.UserExists(spuserField.LoginName))
      {
          var profile8 = profileManager8.GetUserProfile(spuserField.LoginName);
           string personUrl8 = profile8.PersonalSite.Url;

            string userNames = userItem8["Title"].ToString();


                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["LoginName"] = userNames;
                row["NavigateUrl"] = personUrl8;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);



      }
}
RepeaterLinks.DataSource = dt;
RepeaterLinks.DataBind();
```

I hope your issue will be resolved using above code.

Please mark it as answer if it will solve your issue